# In Vue.js 3, why do I have to use the value property on ref, but not on reactive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Basically, the title already says it all: In Vue.js 3, why do I have to use the `value` property on `ref`, but not on `reactive`?

I understand that `ref` is for simple values, such as booleans, numbers, …, and that `reactive` is for complex values such as objects and arrays. What I do not get is:

- Why do I need to specify `value` when I want to access a `ref`'s value, but not if I use `reactive`? Isn't this an inconsistency in the API, or is there an actual technical reason why it *has* to be this way?
- Why am I not able to use one for both? In other words: Is there a technical reason why there isn't a single function which decides, depending on the type of the given value, how to wrap this internally?

I assume that I am missing something and it's not *that* easy. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you find something helpful in my answer or i should delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Ref and Reactive are both reactive variable wrappers.

```
const refVar = ref(true)
const reactiveVar = reactive({ haha: 'LoL' })
```

Here both `refVar` and `reactiveVar` are just wrapper variables to keep reactivity for their values inside.
And as you said, difference between `ref` and `reactive` is that `ref` is for single variable and `reactive` is for dictionary-structured variable.

`ref` looks after the changes in its `value` property and once changed it emits reactive event, so that observers can be updated automatically. But `reactive` looks after all its properties.

If you use only reactive, it would be very uncomfortable to keep reactivity for single variables.

```
const refSingle = reactive({ value: 'I wanna be used with Ref' })
```

And you should call `refSingle.value` all the time on template side.

If you use only ref, it would be very difficult to keep reactivity for dict-typed variables.

```
const reactiveDict = ref({
  type: 'dictionary',
  purpose: 'reactive'
})
```

In this case, if you use it in script, you should use `value` property every time.

```
reactiveDict.value = {
  ...reactiveDict.value,
  purpose: 'ref'
}
```

In this case, you can use `reactive` rather than `ref`.